# Merge arrays to object and object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So I have little bit of a tricky problem right here:

I'm getting 5x2 arrays from this function

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var name = $('.lesson-space:eq( ' + i + ' ) > .lesson').map(function(){return $(this).data('name');}).get();
    var color = $('.lesson-space:eq( ' + i + ' ) > .lesson').map(function(){return $(this).data('color');}).get();
  };
```

For each of these 5 repeats I want to put the two arrays into an object like this

```
     {
        "name": "deutsch",
        "color": "red"
      },
      {
        "name": "mathe",
        "color": "blue"
      },
      {
        "name": "sport",
        "color": "darkblue"
      },
      {
        "name": "franz",
        "color": "yellow"
      }
```

These objects should be put now into in array. So in the end I would like to have 5 arrays (from the first code snipped) put into one array like this

```
[
[
    ...
],[
    ...
],[
    ...
],[
    ...
],[
    ...
]
```

]

I know it's a bit complicated...

Comment: underscore or lo-dash would be able to help you achieve this more easily... if you don'd mind the dependency add.

Comment: also why would you switch back and forth between object and array structure? or do you want to put 5 objects, inside an array, which is inside another array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you want to do something like this

```
var res  = [],
    data = {}; 

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

  data = $('.lesson-space:eq( ' + i + ' ) > .lesson').map(function () {
    var name  = $(this).data('name');
    var color = $(this).data('color');

    if (!name || !color) {
      return null;
    }

    return {
      name:  name,
      color: color
    }
  }).get();

  res.push(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've understood you requirements correctly, however I think this is what you're looking for

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    result.push($('.lesson-space:eq('+i+') > .lesson').get().map(function(){
        return {
            name: $(this).data('name'),
            color: $(this).data('name')
        };
    }));
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: you have to put .get() at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var mainArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    var o = {};
    o.name = name[i];
    o.color = color[i];
    mainArray.push([o])
}
```